# Is it possible to have separate SQLite databases within the same Django project?

Tags: database, django, sqlite, orm

I was considering creating a separate SQLite database for certain apps on a Django project.
However, I did not want to use direct SQLite access if possible.
Django-style ORM access to these database would be ideal.
Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already supported http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

Answer (score 5):

Yes - the low-level API for this is in place, it's just missing a convenient high-level API at the moment. These quotes are from [James Bennett (Django's release manager) on programming reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/6zinj/django_10_released/):

> It's been there -- in an extremely low-level API for those who look at the codebase -- for months now (every `QuerySet` is backed by a `Query`, which in turn accepts a DB connection as an argument). There isn't any high-level documented API for it, but I know people who are already doing and have been doing stuff like multiple-DB/sharding scenarios.
>
> ...it's not necessarily something that needs a big write-up; the `__init__()` method of `QuerySet` accepts a keyword argument `query`, which should be an instance of `django.db.models.sql.Query`. The `__init__()` method of `Query`, in turn, accepts a keyword argument `connection`, which should be an instance of (a backend-specific subclass for your DB of) `django.db.backends.BaseDatabaseWrapper`.
>
> From there, it's pretty easy; you could, for example, override `get_query_set()` on a manager to always return a `QuerySet` using the connection you want, or set up things like sharding logic to figure out which DB to use based on incoming query parameters, etc., etc.

Answer (score 2):

Currently no -- each project uses one database, and every app must exist within it. If you want to have an app-specific database, you cannot do so through the Django ORM. See the Django wiki page on [Multiple Database Support](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleDatabaseSupport).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible yet, but there is some talk of it on the wiki, [Multiple Database Support in Django](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleDatabaseSupport). It was also brought up during the [keynote on the future of Django at DjangoCon 2008](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1Qr9rSBGBE) and made one of the higher priority issues.